What's the difference between @GetMapping and @GetExchange?
From Spring 6, there are the introduction of @GetExchange, @PostExchange, @PutExchange, @DeleteExchange, @PatchExchange.
As I know, we already have the same annotations that do the samething @GetMapping,
@PostMapping, @PutMapping, @DeleteMapping, @PatchMapping.
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.service.annotation.GetExchange;

@RestController
public class Controller {
    
    @GetMapping("mapping")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMapping() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("mapping");
    }
    
    @GetExchange("exchange")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getExchange() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("exchange");
    }
}

My questions,

What is the diffrence between the two annotations.
When and where should we use @GetMapping and @GetExchange?


They don't do the same thing. @GetMapping is for controllers that receive requests, the @GetExchange is for the declarative HTTP clients you can write and are intended to be used on interfaces.

already read the doc, it says: GetExchange Shortcut for @HttpExchange for HTTP GET requests. and for the GetMapping: Annotation for mapping HTTP GET requests onto specific handler methods.
Specifically, @GetMapping is a composed annotation that acts as a shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)., But I don't understand when and where should I use each one as they can do the same thing

They can but they are for different purposes as stated one is for the server (receiving side) the other for the client (sending side).

Both the @GetMapping and @GetExchange are composed annotations and to see the difference you should be looking at the @RequestMapping and @HttpExchange methods documentation.
Basically the @HttpExchange is there for writing declarative HTTP clients. Which is an interface which you can inject into your code and call a HTTP endpoint.
public interface MyClient {

  @GetExchange("/some/url/{variable}")
  ResponseEntity<SomeResult> foo(@PathVariable variable)

}

When you inject this it will dynamically create a client which you can use to invoke an HTTP endpoint.
Traditionally the @RequestMapping (and composed annotations) are to be used to define such an endpoint. However if you yourself control both the client and the endpoint you could also have your endpoint implement the same interface (re-using the contract). Which is the reason the @HttpExchange also works for endpoint.
However what you can express with @HttpExchange is less then what you can express with @RequestMapping so there are some limitations with those annotations.
More information can also be found in the reference guide, which explain things in more detail.

The reference documentation says this about @HttpExchange (and implicitly about the other @XxxExchange):

While the main purpose of @HttpExchange is to abstract HTTP client code with a generated proxy, the HTTP Interface on which such annotations are placed is a contract neutral to client vs server use. In addition to simplifying client code, there are also cases where an HTTP Interface may be a convenient way for servers to expose their API for client access. This leads to increased coupling between client and server and is often not a good choice, especially for public API’s, but may be exactly the goal for an internal API. It is an approach commonly used in Spring Cloud, and it is why @HttpExchange is supported as an alternative to @RequestMapping for server side handling in controller classes.
@HttpExchange and @RequestMapping have differences. @RequestMapping can map to any number of requests by path patterns, HTTP methods, and more, while @HttpExchange declares a single endpoint with a concrete HTTP method, path, and content types.
For method parameters and returns values, generally, @HttpExchange supports a subset of the method parameters that @RequestMapping does. Notably, it excludes any server-side specific parameter types. For details, see the list for @HttpExchange and @RequestMapping.

So the primary purpose of the XxxExchange annotations is to allow Spring to create HTTP client code for you.

If you only create a RestController I would prefer the @RequestMapping since this gives more options for the controller code.
If you create internal APIs with controllers and clients then you can use @HttpExchange


The primary purpose of the @HttpExchange family of annotations is to define an interface that can be used to create a proxy using HttpServiceProxyFactory. That is, it's most useful when your app is the client initiating the HTTP request.
@HttpExchange("/persons")
interface PersonService {
    @GetExchange("/{id}")
    Person getPerson(@PathVariable Long id);

    @PostExchange
    void add(@RequestBody Person person);
}

HttpServiceProxyFactory factory = /* something */;
PersonService service = factory.createClient(PersonService.class);

That interface can also be implemented directly in a controller, as your example shows, but it comes with more restrictions on the parameter types than the @HttpMapping family of annotations; since it may be used on the client or the server, none of the server-specific things are available. That might be useful if you have both a Spring client and server and you want them to share the same code, and you don't require any of the server-specific parameters.
The @HttpMapping family of annotations support a wider number of parameter types so if your code is only used on the server (i.e. you don't have a Spring client), then using those will give you more options.
